# Use Zend Gdata to share Google Docs folder

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, zend-gdata

I created a folder using Zend Gdata function `createFolder('FOLDERNAME')`, but how to share this folder with someone with `$name` and `$email`?

Actually, I succeeded with google-api-php-client by add permission into the folder:

```
$permission = new Google_Permission();
$permission->setValue($email);
$permission->setType('user');
$permission->setRole('writer');
...
$service->permissions->insert($fileid, $permission);
```

Seems like no api is provided for this job in Zend. What I want to do is to share it with Zend. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried this? https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData/blob/3c2e19a5946592fb7fdd52628e833d9fcfdabc75/library/ZendGData/Docs.php#L273

Comment: @ViniciusPinto Hi, thanks for your answer. But this version seems not maintained, and no examples or docs I can refer to. I do not know how to connect may Google account with this library. Can you give some example please?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice that. Why don't you use the Google library then? If you really want to use the Zend lib, you might be able to adapt some examples from here http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.introduction.html

Comment: @ViniciusPinto Thanks, Vinicius! I decided to use Google library.